# SFTP Directory Shortcut \ Bridge

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/tools/limiting-access-with-sftp-jails-on-debian-and-ubuntu) to create a **SFTP** group and to limit users within that group just to specific folders.

So I ended up with:

```
/home/my-user/docs
/home/my-user/public_html
```

... and I want that `public_html` folder to be basically a shortcut or something similar so that when users upload files, these files will end up here:

```
/var/www/html/my-folder/
```

How can I do that?

Note, I'm not Linux script expert, so I would appreciate step by step explanation using terminal commands .

Comment: Maybe also ask [here](http://askubuntu.com/)?

Comment: while creating user you need to assign their home directory as `/var/www/html/my-folder/`